# Could you plese help me how to draw an image instead of the rectangle?

Tags: lua, love2d

My player is a rectangle and I really want it to be a player I draw myself. So I decided to ask you guys for help since I couldn't figure it out myself, I'm a bit new to programming.

Its programmed in Lua using love2d.

This is the code where I draw the rectangle.

```
function love.draw()
camera:set()

love.graphics.setColor( 255, 161, 65 )
love.graphics.rectangle("fill", player.x - player.w/2, player.y - player.h/2, player.w, player.h)

love.graphics.setColor( 255, 255, 255 )
map:draw()

camera:unset()
end
```

If you could comment a code with a method to get an image to be the rectangle it would help so much! Please ask if you need to see more code!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to [load the image](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.newImage).

```
player.image = love.graphics.newImage("mydude.png")
```

Then you have to [draw the image](http://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw):

```
love.graphics.draw(player.image, player.x, player.y)
```

I suggest you walk through some of the tutorials, and try to search in google and the documentation for your questions. [("love2d draw picture")](https://www.google.com/search?q=love2d+draw+picture)

Comment: I can impory a pic but now the problem is that is crashes with lots of errors when i try to put it in

Comment: Try reading what the errors say, or editing them into your post.